# Issue in updating the last row of listview

Tags: android, listview

I am using a custom adapter to populate a listview in android. I am developing a chat app using XMPP. Inside the message listener I am inserting the msg to local sqlite db and populating the listview. When I am sending a message I am inserting that message to local db and is populating the list view. When a message is sent I will be getting the response back that it is delivered. So my need is that I need to show a text sending in only the last item of the list view and all other text in the other rows of the list view needs to be shown as delivered at that time. Then when I get the delivered status, I need to change the text to delivered in only the last row of the list view.

How can I do this? Please help.

***Updated***

Adding the latest code from the adapter here:

```
else if(status.equals("Received message")) {
    if(position == chatHistoryVector.size()-1) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {  
                imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sending);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deliverd);
    } else {
        imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deliverd);
    }
}
```

Here the handler is not working. I am getting only the delivered image displayed.

Please help

Comment: I have managed to update the last row of the list view by checking the last position of the last list view inside the adapter. I tried by updating the last row from the activity that holds the list view by using notifyDataSetChanged(), but it was not working as I expected. It is almost working fine. I am editing the above question to add the block of code that I am currently using. Now my issue is that inside the if condition that checks the "Received message" text. I need to first display the image sending and then the delivered image. Please help

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deliverd); after the runnable has finished executing?

Comment: @Premsuraj I am doing like that only. after the post delayed statement only I have written imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deliverd);

Comment: Please check the answer I have posted

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have posted the

```
imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deliverd);
```

will executed immediately and your Runnable will be queued for execution after one second. That is why the delivered status is being shown before the sending status.

Try this
Somewhere in your class declare a new handler

```
Handler deliveredHandler = new Handler()
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
     imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deliverd);
  }
};
```

And change the if condition as below

```
if(position == chatHistoryVector.size()-1) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {  
                imgStatus.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.sending);
                deliveredHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 1000);
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
    }
```